# Проблема с IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: Условие задачи]

```
    n=int(input())
    x=int(0)
    a=[]
    for i in range(1,13):
        a.append(0)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        x=int(input())
        a[x]=a[x]+1

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,13):
            if a[j] == i:
                print(j, a[j])

Почему если в ввести в качестве входных данных

    4
    12
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Mag/Desktop/untitled-1.py", line 8, in <module>
        a[x]=a[x]+1
    builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаёте список на 12 элементов. В Питоне списки нумеруются с нуля, а задачи по условию нумеруются с единицы. Вам нужно брать индекс на единицу меньше, чем номер задачи. Если немного упростить код, то первая часть задачи с вводом данных выглядеть будет так:

```
n = int(input())
a = [0]*12
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input())
    a[x - 1] += 1
```

Точно так же  во второй части кода нужно проходить либо по задачам с 1-й по 12-ю, но при обращении к списку уменьшать индекс на один:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,13):
         if a[j - 1] == i:
             print(j, a[j - 1])
```

либо проходить по индексам от 0 до 12, но уже прибавлять единицу к номеру задачи:

```
for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(12):
        if a[j] == i:
            print(j + 1, a[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что, массив **а** содержит 12 элементов с индексами 0-11, а во втором цикле **for** идет обращение к 12-му индексу, которого нет.